# Parsing with lxml and xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to parse a specific table of a website

On this website, I need to get the columns (Name and Title, Vocation, Level) using xlml and xpath on python.

So far I have this code:

```
import lxml.html
import requests
from lxml import html


url = "http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=guilds&page=view&GuildName=Black%20Widow"
html = lxml.html.parse(url)
list = html.xpath("//table[@class='TableContent'][1]/tr/td[2]/text()")
```

The `list` suppose to give me the text of the first column "Name and Title" but what I'm receiving is a list full of `'\xa0'`

I did make the same code on vb.net using [HTML agility pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and it runs smooth, and I can post here the code of the vb.net app so you can see better what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get values from `"Name and Title"` column you can try below `XPath`:

```
//table[@class='TableContent']//td/a/text()
```

Also note that you shouldn't use `"list"` as variable name as it is a name of `Python` built-in class

Comment: Excellent that's what im looking about, now i will start to work on how to pass those info to a mysql datatable :D